# If row status is 1 show the approved status in the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to output statement you are approve if the row status  = 1, the data can be output now i just want the statement saying approve.

**here's my code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Nominee Name</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>StudentID</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>View File</th>
                <th>Nominee Photo</th>
                <th>Nominated by</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($nominees as $noms) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['year']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['department']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['studentid']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['position']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $noms['pdf']; ?>"></a></td>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $noms['photo']; ?>" style='width:50px;height:50px;'></td>
                    <td><?php echo $noms['nomname']; ?></td>
                    <?php if ($noms['approve'] == 1) { ?>
                        <td>Approve</td>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <td>pending</td>
                    <?php } ?>

                </tr>

            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the $nominees array returns the status?

Comment: yes sir , the $nominees array return to status

Comment: You're already using an `if` construct in that code, what exactly are you having problems with? Is it that `$nom['approve']` should be `$noms['approve']`?

Comment: oh  thank you man , now i already solve it hahah xd , i think i have to sleep now hahahah thank you by the way <3  i feel stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $nominees array returns the stays, then you can  do like this

```
<?php if ( $nom['status'] == 1) { ?>
                            <td>Approve</td>
                       <?php }else{ ?>
                       <td>pending</td>
                        <?php }?>
```

Comment: <?php  if ( $noms['approve'] == 1) { ?> <td>Approve</td>  
           <?php }else{ ?>
        <td>pending</td>
            <?php }?>
                       
                        </tr>